# Download the Internet Explorer on SUSE-Linux server

Tags: linux, suse

I am interested in downloading the Internet Explorer on my SUSE-linux server which is telnet'd from my local linux machine.

I need to install the Wireshark and SNMP browsing tools on the server and would like to therefore have an internet explorer installed on the server.

Please help me with the installation.

Comment: There's no Linux version of IE. You can try to install it using the Wine windows emulator.

Comment: I don't get why you need Internet Explorer to install Wireshark…

Comment: To install things on SUSE, you should probably use yast, or zypper. To download things not on the distro repositories, you should probably use wget or curl.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Exploder only runs on Windows machines.  You might be wanting to install all of this on a Windows Server and then run these tools against a Linux machine, but you're not going to natively be successful loading IE on a Linux Server.

There is an option that I'll mention you can check out Crossover Office from Codeweavers, it's got the ability to run the appropriate WINE drivers and environment so that you could do what you are asking, but there is no guarantee that the overall scheme of running Wireshark will work.